# in-effficiency in flink job like : INSERT INTO hive_table select orgId, 2.0 , pdate, '02' from users limit 10000 where user is a kafka table

Tags: apache-flink

The system should just pick 10000 message and finish . Here is what is forever running. it taking in 78 G data and forever going. don't know if this default behavior. Also. it never commit in commit sink.
Above is running on flink1.12 scala 2.12 build with all hive 3.1.2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zw75k.png)

Comment: the more trouble part is the 10000 recorded is never commit into hive table, the data is all in hdfs system.

Comment: understand if optimizer of sql cannot stop the job.

Answer (score 0):

The streaming file sink only commits while checkpointing. Perhaps you need to enable and configure checkpointing.

Comment: all checkpont is cofiguer at flink-conf.yaml system level into hdfs

Comment: the job is submitted through flik sql client

Comment: what is the correct way to config the checkpoint in flink-sql.yaml filess?

Comment: would you please share a sql.yaml for flink sql client?